# Discuss Convergence of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Discuss the convergence of the given series (Please apply any test to show convergence or divergence):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \tan\left(\frac 1k\right)$$

Comment: That’s homework, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the *Limit Comparison Test*.

**The Limit Comparison Test.** Suppose $a_k,b_k>0$ for all $k$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k}=c$ where $0<c<\infty$, then either both $\sum a_k$ and $\sum b_k$ converge or both diverge.

We can use the Limit Comparison Test to show that $\sum \tan(1/k)$ *diverges*.

Let $a_k=\tan(1/k)$ and $b_k=1/k$. Then
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k}
= \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\tan(1/k)}{1/k}
= \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\tan(t)}{t}
\stackrel{\text{LH}}{=} \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sec^2(t)}{1}
= \sec^2(0)
=1
$$
By the Limit Comparison Test, either both $\sum a_k$ and $\sum b_k$ converge or both diverge. Since $\sum b_k$ diverges, it follows that $\sum a_k$ diverges.

Comment: nitpick: Isn't $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\tan(\frac1{k})}{\frac1{k}} = \lim_{t\to0} \tan(t)/t$ valid and shorter?

Comment: @Sabyasachi I guess so.

Comment: Thanks Brian. That helped. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** For small positive $x$, we have $\tan x\gt x$.

**Remark:** We can prove this by noting that $\tan 0=0$ and that $\tan x-x$ is an increasing function on $(0,\pi/2)$.